# C# - Wait for 2s before doing next task

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
private void materialRaisedButton16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("RobloxPlayerBeta"))
        {
            process.Kill();
        }

        materialRaisedButton16.Text = "Successfully killed process!";

        // sleep for 2s WITHOUT freezing GUI

        materialRaisedButton16.Text = "Click to kill process";
    }
```

Hi, my code is above. I need the text of the button to change for 2s then change back to the original. How is this possible?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 3):

**Implement like this**

```
private async Task DelayTask()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000); //2000 = 2sec
        DoyourStuffHere();
        materialRaisedButton16.Text = "Click to kill process";
    }
```

*And Call It Like This*

```
     private void materialRaisedButton16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("RobloxPlayerBeta"))
    {
        process.Kill();
    }

    materialRaisedButton16.Text = "Successfully killed process!";

    // sleep for 2s WITHOUT freezing GUI

    Task taketime = this.DelayTask();
    }
```

Comment: Hello, what a friend of mine, I see that it has progressed
Take my upvote for it; You and I like the development of video games. chance?

Comment: @Héctor Manuel Martinez Durán, lel ya i love game making but i left it in past

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: But if you just said that you left it in the past, that means you left it

Comment: What happened with you? some time ago that you do not feel

Comment: Mmmmm, I do not understand what happened, lately you do not participate in SO

Comment: Well, in any case, look at my most recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49594114/keyup-event-is-doubling-using-mahapps-metro/49594422#49594422

Answer (score 2):

Not freezing the GUI requires some form of Mutlitasking. Possibly even Multithreading. Very strictly speaking calling a bunch of helper processes is a primitive form of Multithreading already. Possibly the oldest one, we invented just as we came off Cooperative Multitasking back in the days.

You have many Options to do Multitasking (inlcuding Multithreading) in .NET Async...await. Tasks. Threads. For beginners in Multithreading, I would advise BackgroundWorker generally. I wrote this little intro examples a few years back that I link often:

```
#region Primenumbers
private void btnPrimStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!bgwPrim.IsBusy)
    {
        //Prepare ProgressBar and Textbox
        int temp = (int)nudPrim.Value;
        pgbPrim.Maximum = temp;
        tbPrim.Text = "";

        //Start processing
        bgwPrim.RunWorkerAsync(temp);
    }
}

private void btnPrimCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bgwPrim.IsBusy)
    {
        bgwPrim.CancelAsync();
    }
}

private void bgwPrim_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int highestToCheck = (int)e.Argument;
    //Get a reference to the BackgroundWorker running this code
    //for Progress Updates and Cancelation checking
    BackgroundWorker thisWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

    //Create the list that stores the results and is returned by DoWork
    List<int> Primes = new List<int>();


    //Check all uneven numbers between 1 and whatever the user choose as upper limit
    for(int PrimeCandidate=1; PrimeCandidate < highestToCheck; PrimeCandidate+=2)
    {
        //Report progress
        thisWorker.ReportProgress(PrimeCandidate);
        bool isNoPrime = false;

        //Check if the Cancelation was requested during the last loop
        if (thisWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            //Tell the Backgroundworker you are canceling and exit the for-loop
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }

        //Determin if this is a Prime Number
        for (int j = 3; j < PrimeCandidate && !isNoPrime; j += 2)
        {
            if (PrimeCandidate % j == 0)
                isNoPrime = true;
        }

        if (!isNoPrime)
            Primes.Add(PrimeCandidate);
    }

    //Tell the progress bar you are finished
    thisWorker.ReportProgress(highestToCheck);

    //Save Return Value
    e.Result = Primes.ToArray();
}

private void bgwPrim_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pgbPrim.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void bgwPrim_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    pgbPrim.Value = pgbPrim.Maximum;
    this.Refresh();

    if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
    {
        //Show the Result
        int[] Primes = (int[])e.Result;

        StringBuilder sbOutput = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (int Prim in Primes)
        {
            sbOutput.Append(Prim.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        tbPrim.Text = sbOutput.ToString();
    }
    else 
    {
        tbPrim.Text = "Operation canceled by user or Exception";
    }
}
#endregion
```

Of course in your case, something much simpler could work: A baseline Timer. All you really want is a 2 second delay? Make a TImer set to 2 seconds, no repeat, start it in "materialRaisedButton16_Click". And let it's tick to the rest. All true multithreading really does is allow you to write the same stuff in slightly more readable form (with some tradeoffs for performance).

Comment: wow this code is long, ig you should give short answer to OP , i suggest you to trim the code

Comment: why would you suggest BackgroundWorker in 2018. People need to learn async/await.

Comment: @Crowcoder: Why I agree that async/await is the better thing, you need to learn to walk before you can run. BGW is a good learning tool. It will get you over the issues specific to Multithreading (need to Invoke and Exception swallowing). Wich do cause a lot of longterm problems.

Comment: I disagree. It is more like rock climbing vs running. And you don't need to learn to rock climb before you run. Look at how much code you had to write, I don't think that makes things more clear for beginners, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @Crowcoder: I even mentioned the option of just using a good old timer. Does not even need to be one that has Multithreading Support or anything. Basic Windows.Forms.Timer can do this. However he was already using a form of Multithreading (Multi-Processes) so I was not certain if he wanted to seriously go into Multithreading. Or just wanted a quick and working solution.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way would be:

```
 foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("RobloxPlayerBeta"))
        {
            process.Kill();
        }

        materialRaisedButton16.Text = "Successfully killed process!";

        // sleep for 2s WITHOUT freezing GUI

        Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(()=>{
                materialRaisedButton16.Text = "Click to kill process";
          }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); // this is to make it run in the UI thread again
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Timer.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)
On its tick event you update the text of the button back to the value u need.