# KeyUp event is doubling using "mahapps.metro"

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

Complete project: https://uploadfiles.io/wz8ji

Follow code:

***Code C#:***

```
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Textbox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textbox.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            this.ShowMessageAsync("This is the title", "Some message");
        }
    }
}
```

***Code xaml:***

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Wpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="324" Margin="88,31,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="605">
            <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <TextBox 
                        x:Name="textbox"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Height="23"
                        Margin="10,10,0,0"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap"
                        Text="TextBox"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Width="120"
                        KeyUp="Textbox_KeyUp"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

In my text box, when I quickly erase and type, the event is duplicated. When I delete and type "1" normally, everything is fine.The problem is when I delete and type any very fast character. When I do this quickly, the event is duplicated.

I also use this: http://mahapps.com/

I created another project without using "mahapps", it works right.

Here's how it's happening:

Press the <kbd>backspace</kbd> and release + <kbd>1</kbd> keys quickly.

[image]

Any Solution ?

Comment: Can you add all the events this method is assigned to?

Comment: Mmmm, let me try your code

Comment: @PaulTsai There is no other, that's all.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda looks like you updated the code to include the xaml.

Comment: What action within the if you use to verify if the method is called?

MessageBox? Debug?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Can you double check that the keyup event is not also tied to the control that the Textbox is sitting on? This would cause the keyup to fire multiple times, once for the textbox and once for the other control (grid, stackpanel, etc)

Comment: @PaulTsai Please see my post. I updated.

Comment: @PaulTsai Dialogs shows 2 times in line `this.ShowMessageAsync("This is the title", "Some message");`

Comment: @PaulTsai e.KeyCode solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have submitted your code to different tests and the method is not duplicated...

```
int i = 0;
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(((TextBox)sender).Text != string.Empty)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hello " + ++i);
    }
 }
```

> Verify that another active control has no associated keyboard event, that may be the problem.

[image: Your code works correctly]

## I have tested your code and it works well

As you told me in the chat, you quickly press backspace + 1, well, the error is that your code detects the pulsation of any key as long as the TextBox is not empty, so, what you must do is restrict the use of Back

```
private void Textbox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (textbox.Text != string.Empty && e.Key != Key.Back)
     {
         this.ShowMessageAsync("This is the title", "Some message");
     }
}
```

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Welll, give me a moment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167966/discussion-between-hector-manuel-martinez-duran-and-matheus-miranda).